# swift 4 selector perform with multiple parameters

Tags: swift, selector

I have function definition like this.

```
  @objc  func getSearchList(forString: String?, forPaging: Bool){
```

and I want to perform this function after waiting 0.5 second .(after text change but when fast change , remove callbacks and perform last added)

But when I perform like below, forString parameter is nil and  not cancel old performs.Can someone help me? How can I send multiple parameter to selector and cancel previousperformRequests?

```
 let selector = #selector(SearchViewController.getSearchList(forString : forPaging:))
    NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self, selector: selector, object: previousSearchText)
    self.perform(selector, with: forInputString, afterDelay: 0.5)
    previousSearchText = forInputString
```

Comment: It would probably be easier to use an `OperationQueue` instead of selectors and `perform`.